Apple authentication error on real device but not on simulator [com.apple.AuthenticationServices.Authorization Error Code 1000]
I receive this error when trying to sign in from my Iphone 14, whereas with the simulator it works well:
com.apple.AuthenticationServices.Authorization Error Code 1000
I'm using React Native and Expo Go.
I tried everything that has been said on the topic:

Add sign in capability and restart the app.
Remove other devices from Icloud and rebuild
Add useAppleSignIn to expo config file (app.config.js)

   ios: {
        googleServicesFile: "./GoogleService-Info.plist",
        supportsTablet: true,
        bundleIdentifier: "com.dadyzal",
        buildNumber: "7.0.9",
        usesAppleSignIn: true

    },

I don't have the 3 Entitlements files it might be related to that?
Here is my code but I don't think it's related to that:
 async function onAppleButtonPress() {
    try {
      console.log("Starting Apple login request...");

      // performs login request
      const appleAuthRequestResponse = await appleAuth.performRequest({
        requestedOperation: appleAuth.Operation.LOGIN,
        requestedScopes: [appleAuth.Scope.FULL_NAME, appleAuth.Scope.EMAIL],
      });

      console.log("Answer received from Apple.");

      console.log(appleAuthRequestResponse);

      const appleCredential = auth.AppleAuthProvider.credential(
        appleAuthRequestResponse.identityToken,
        appleAuthRequestResponse.nonce
      );

       await auth().signInWithCredential(appleCredential);

      // Navigate to another screen
      navigation.navigate('Home' as never);
      // } else {
      //   console.log("User is not authenticated.");
      // }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error during Apple login:", error);
      setError(error.message);
    }
  }

I tried everything that has been said on the topic:

Add sign in capability in Xcode and restart the app.

Remove other devices from Icloud and rebuild

Add useAppleSignIn to expo config file (app.config.js)

set a  team in Xcode




Hey, were you able to get it working?
